# Dynamics CRM OrganizationServiceContext - Suddenly Limiting Records Returned?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Bit of background to this...
in my company we have loads of C# jobs that execute at various points throughout the day (mainly overnight) to insert/update records in our Dynamics 365 online environment.
We have been in the cloud for over 12 months and these jobs have all been working absolutely fine until a few days ago.

All of a sudden, the jobs that read existing records back from CRM using the CRM SDK DLLS via the ServiceContext.CreateQuery method, have now started to throw OUtOfMemory exceptions once the default timeout has been reached (we default it to 10 minutes).
For example, we have about 150,000 contact records which would ordinarily be read back (just the contactid and one other custom field) in under 30 seconds that are now bombing out in multiple C# jobs.
The code works if I limit the where clause to include a specific contactid GUID or read back records from an entity that has a small number of records in it.

It is like as if there is now a cap on the no. of records you can read back or something like that.
I have seen this problem before if trying to read millions of records back in one go, but not in the region of 100-150k records. This has always worked just fine until now.
Anyone else experienced something similar and/or know how to resolve this?
I know I can refactor the code to use the service object in conjunction with QueryExpression instead (and read back 5000 records per page at a time) but want to see if there is a way around that as we have a huge amount of code that would need to be reworked.

Thanks

Sample code below...

```
var records =
            (
                from a in CrmConnection._serviceContext.CreateQuery("contact")
                where a["statecode"] != null
                && a["code"] != null
                && ((OptionSetValue)a["statecode"]).Value == 0
                select new
                {
                    ContactId = (Guid)a["contactid"],
                    Code = (string)a["code"]
                }
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: sorry can't you paginate ?

Comment: Yeah but I'm trying to figure out why this happened all of a sudden and if there is a way to get it working again as before without changing any code. I've never had to page results around the 100-150k mark only where the number of records was much larger than that.

Comment: Late last week I was seeing intermittent connection and performance issues with Dynamics online. How is the issue today?

Comment: It has actually miraculously started working again since yesterday after 9-10 days of not working. Tried logging a support ticket with Microsoft but was a waste of time. They just kept repeating "nothing has changed at our end" etc etc. Something has to have been going on in the background though.